# Unkillable process after connection lost to Samba share?

Tags: centos, samba, smb

Using [this](http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/WindowsShares) manual I've mounted a Samba share. I'm copying files to it using a Python script.

Everything is working fine until some problem with the network occurs. After that I get unkillable processes in a "D" state. Furthermore, even standard programs like `ls` can faint and become unkillable if used on the mounted share.

The only solution is to change the path in the config files of `automount`, restart `automount` service, and use the new path. But unkillable processes are still there, of course.

So the question is: how to avoid this situation?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `mount.smbfs` to mount you can use the `soft` option, see the [man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/8/mount_smbfs/):

> ```
>          soft    Make the mount soft.  Fail file system calls after a num-
>                  ber of seconds.
> ```